# How can I make a dynamic column on the ON clause of JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like these:

```
// questions_and_answers
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| id |    subject    |           body         | related | deleted |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
| 1  | subject1      | question1              | NULL    | 0       |
| 2  |               | answer1                | 1       | 0       |
| 3  | subject2      | question2              | NULL    | 0       |
| 4  |               | answer2                | 3       | 1       |
| 5  |               | answer3                | 3       | 0       |
| 6  | subject3      | question3              | NULL    | 1       |
| 7  |               | answer4                | 6       | 0       |
+----+---------------+------------------------+---------+---------+
-- related column contains either NULL for questions or the id of its question for answers

// viewed_times
+----+-------------+---------+
| id | question_id | user_id |
+----+-------------+---------+
| 1  | 1           | 123     |
| 2  | 1           | 456     |
| 3  | 6           | 123     |
| 4  | 3           | 123     |
| 5  | 6           | 456     |
| 6  | 1           | 789     |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

I need to search in the `body` of both questions and answers.

**EX1:** Here is the expected result for `answer4` entry:

```
+------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| question_subject |     body     | total_question_viewed |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| subject3         | answer4      | 2                     |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

**EX2:** Here is the expected result for `question1`:

```
+------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| question_subject |     body     | total_question_viewed |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| subject1         | question1    | 3                     |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

---

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(qa2.subject, qa1.subject) question_subject, 
       qa1.body
FROM questions_and_answers qa1
LEFT JOIN questions_and_answers qa2 ON qa1.related = qa2.id
WHERE qa1.body = ":entry"
```

My current query returns the first two column of the expected result. How can I calculate `total_question_viewed` value?

The point is, some times I have to join `qa1.id` with `viewed_times.question_id` and sometimes else I have to do that join on `qa2.id` equals `viewed_times.question_id`. How can I handle that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `coalesce` to join on right column:

```
select subject as question_subject,
    body,
    count(*) as total_question_viewed
from questions_and_answers qa
inner join viewed_items v 
    on coalesce(qa.related, qa.id) = v.question_id
where body like '%answer4%'
group by question_subject, body, v.question_id
```

See [live demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1ca4/2)

Comment: i won't advice using this on large table(s) because MySQL optimizer can never use a index on this `on coalesce(qa.related, qa.id) = v.question_id` statement.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Agree. On this very specific design OP could replace `on` condition with  `v.question_id IN (qa.related, qa.id)`

Comment: If I use `IN` clause instead, then would it take a benefit of indexes? @revo

Comment: Because in reality there is `where` clause and I simply can use `IN` clause. There isn't join in reality, it's a subquery.

Comment: @MartinAJ Yes, it should. It acts like an `OR` as `v.question_id = qa.related or  v.question_id = qa.id`. You don't have an answer which its `id` (not `related` id) is a question's `id` - it never happens. So you could use `IN` instead of `COALESCE`, safely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888481/how-can-i-use-coalesce-in-where-clause-optimally

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is another `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(qa2.subject, qa1.subject) as question_subject, 
       qa1.body,
       COUNT(vt.question_id)
FROM questions_and_answers qa1 LEFT JOIN
     questions_and_answers qa2
     ON qa1.related = qa2.id LEFT JOIN
     viewed_times vt
     ON vt.question_id = qa1.id
WHERE qa1.body = ":entry"
GROUP BY question_subject, qa1.body;
```

Comment: In `ON vt.question_id = qa1.id`, sometimes `qa1.id` is the id of an answer, while in this case we need to join `vt.question_id` with the id of its question. Because `viewed_times` table just keeps the id of questions.

Comment: Probably it would work `ON vt.question_id = COALESCE(qa1.related, qa1.id)` .. What you think?